# Other ways to show $y_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+{1\over x_k}\right)$ is bounded, where $x_n$ is another sequence with given properties.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Problem statement:

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of natural numbers such that $S_n$ defined by:
>   $$
> S_n = {1\over x_1} + {1\over x_2} + {1\over x_2} + \dots + {1\over x_n}
> $$
>   is bounded.
>
> Show that $y_n$ is bounded given:
>   $$
> y_n = \prod_{k=1}^n\left(1 + {1\over x_k}\right)
> $$

From the problem statement we know that $S_n$ is bounded. Let's try to take log of $y_n$:
$$
\ln y_n = \ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1 + {1\over x_k}\right)\right) = \ln\left(1 + {1\over x_1}\right) + \ln\left(1 + {1\over x_2}\right) + \dots +\ln\left(1 + {1\over x_n}\right)
$$

We know that $x_k$ is a natural number and therefore $x_k > -1$. Based on that we may use the following inequality:

$$
\ln(1+x) < x, \; \forall x>-1
$$

Thus:

$$
\ln y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\ln\left(1+{1\over x_k}\right)\right) <\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over x_k} = S_n
$$

But we know that $S_n$ is bounded, now given $S_n < M$:
$$
\ln y_n <M \iff y_n <e^M
$$

Thus $e^M$ is some constant being an upper bound for $y_n$ and $y_n > 0$. So finally:

$$
0<y_n < e^M
$$

**Question:**

> I would like to know whether my proof is valid and find(if possible) a precalculus way of proving this, since $\ln(1+x) < x$ requires derivatives to be proven.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: There are probably a dozen proofs of $\ln(1+x) < x$, and what you consider “precalculus” might depend on your definition of the logarithm.

Comment: @MartinR for my case calculus start with the definition of limits.

Comment: @MartinR I use the following $a^{log_aN} = N$. So $a^x=N$ and $x=log_aN$. Are there other definition of $\log$ i do not know of?

Comment: How do you define $e$ the natural base of logarithm without limit?

Comment: @Zvi well, that's a good point. I've just referred to the book i'm using. And it defines only $\log_a{x}$ for arbitrary $a$ and $\log_{10}{x}$. So since $e$ is defined either through limit or through Taylor series I assume there is no way to define it without referring to either of those. Guess the only way is to take it for granted before the definition of a limit.

Comment: @Zvi I've never thought about what you've pointed out. The reason I'm requesting precalculus solutions is because i've skipped the section before limits and proceeded directly to limits, derivatives, series expansions and further. But then I decided to return back to what've been skipped. So using $\log_ex$ fell very natural to me, before your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's solution is fine, but it is technically not a precalculus solution.  Here is a solution without even using logarithm.  I only require that $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ are positive real numbers such that $S_n$ converges.  (Well, I could also allow negative $x_k$ as long as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x_k}$ converges absolutely, but because the OP wants an elementary method, this more general assumption is not being made.)

Since $S_n$ is bounded, there can be only finitely many $k$ with $0<x_k<1$.  We claim that, for some $m$, $$\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}<\frac12$$
for every $n>m$.  Suppose contrary that, for each $m$, there exists $n_m>m$ for which
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{n_m}\frac{1}{x_k}\geq \frac12.$$
Set $t_0=0$, $t_1=n_{t_0}$, $t_2=n_{t_1}$, $t_3=n_{t_2}$, $\ldots$.  Then,
$$\sum_{k=t_j+1}^{t_{j+1}}\frac{1}{x_k}\geq \frac12$$
for $j=0,1,2,\ldots$.  In particular,
$$S_{t_l}=\sum_{k=1}^{t_l}\frac{1}{x_k}=\sum_{j=0}^{l-1}\sum_{k=t_j+1}^{t_{j+1}}\frac{1}{x_k}\geq \sum_{j=0}^{l-1}\frac12\geq \frac{l}{2}$$
for all $l=1,2,3,\ldots$.  This contradicts the assumption that $S_n$ is bounded.

So, there does exist $m$ such that $\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}<\frac12$ for all $n>m$.  Thus,
$$y_n=\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)\prod_{k=m+1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)$$
for $n>m$.  Now,
$$\prod_{k=m+1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)=\frac{\prod_{k=m+1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k^2}\right)}{\prod_{k=m+1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k}\right)}<\frac{1}{\prod_{k=m+1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k}\right)}.$$
By induction,
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k}\right)\geq 1-\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}>\frac12.$$
Hence, for $n>m$, 
$$y_n<2\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)<\infty.$$
Because $m$ is fixed, the sequence $\left(y_n\right)$ is indeed bounded.

Comment: Well, if $x_k$ can be negative but $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\,\dfrac1{x_k}$ converges absolutely, then you can replace $x_k$ by $\left|x_k\right|$ in certain places to establish that $\left|y_n\right|$ is bounded.

Comment: I think you made a typo.  I fixed it, and hopefully, you wouldn't mind.